# X,Y coordinates of text cursor position

Tags: delphi, caret, delphi-6, text-cursor

How to find out X,Y screen coordinates of a text cursor in a control **whatever is focused at current time**? It may be `TEdit`, `TMemo` or any other control with text cursor.

I need it in order to display a window with a choice of alternative characters user can enter. This window should pop up on a special key combination, with its top left corner near to the caret in currently active editor. Because I did'nt want to make individual processing for each editing control, I do it application wide in `Application.OnMessage` handler.

Comment: You can try [`GetCaretPos()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcaretpos). You will need to convert from client to screen coordinates.

Comment: Olivier, Thank you. it works like `if Windows.GetCaretPos(cp) and Windows.ClientToScreen(GetFocus(), cp) then begin end;`. Do you want some points for an answer?

Comment: Look at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34520/Getting-Caret-Position-Inside-Any-Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetCaretPos` can do the trick.

It works like

```
if Windows.GetCaretPos(cp) and Windows.ClientToScreen(GetFocus(), cp) then begin
  //.......
end;
```